# Moving with cursor image left slide to right with javascript in Widget code

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, widget

I want this widget code. I checked all posts, but they do not help

this code worked without HTML & CSS in Widget.
But i want to do like mouse hover like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nP7Lc/285/) with below code. my bad english

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var imgObj = null;
var animate ;
function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'absolute'; 
   imgObj.style.top = '240px';
   imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';
   moveRight();
} 
function moveRight(){
    if (parseInt(imgObj.style.left)<=10)
    {
        imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
        imgObj.style.visibility='visible';
        animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
       //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
    }
    else
       stop();
       f();
}

function stop(){
   clearTimeout(animate);
}
window.onload =init;
//-->
</script>
<img id="myImage" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LxuD_Ceq6NrRGBW2mF_6Cy9zeO_vqkV8ZTRMdzjc_LxE0InnXBLp1_BkWuyhlg0EMJPt-Njzzp5_4cuR562m6dh8QNTW_1kzsf9pXcXiKI2ZK6wEMJH2TAAiQqpQUewNMKI=s0-d" style="margin-left:170px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with just CSS3 `transition`. Check below update.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
img {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: -65px; /* Adjust this value to expose the image */
  left: 0;
  transition: left .5s;
}
img:hover {
  left: 65px; /* Use same value as used as negative margin */
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LxuD_Ceq6NrRGBW2mF_6Cy9zeO_vqkV8ZTRMdzjc_LxE0InnXBLp1_BkWuyhlg0EMJPt-Njzzp5_4cuR562m6dh8QNTW_1kzsf9pXcXiKI2ZK6wEMJH2TAAiQqpQUewNMKI=s0-d" />
```

Comment: i dont like to see in main page !! i want to show this in each posts !!

Comment: i tried this code just now.. my template turns more left & errors